# What is the purpose of format specifier "%qd" in `printf()`?

Tags: c, gcc, format-specifiers, openbsd

I saw format specifier `%qd` when browsing [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/clang/blob/master/test/Sema/format-strings.c) code. Then I checked in GCC compiler, it's working fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{  
    long long num = 1;
    printf("%qd\n", num);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the purpose of format specifier `%qd` in `printf()`?

Comment: The more portable example would probably be with `int64_t`. But not a bad Q&A

Comment: The `q` length modifier is a non-portable, non-reliable, antiquated, deprecated way of writing `ll`.  Use `ll` in your code; encourage those who maintain the code on GitHub to upgrade to standard C99 formats.

Comment: `printf` formats are implemented by the runtime library, not by the compiler. This is not a gcc (or egcs, or llvm) issue. On my Ubuntu 20.04 system, for example, `%qd` works with gcc and glibc, but fails with gcc and musl -- same compiler, different runtime libraries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> `%qd` was intended to handle 64 bits comfortably on all
> machines, and was originally a bsd-ism (`quad_t`).
>
> However, `egcs` (and `gcc` before that) treats it as equivalent to `ll`, which
> is not always equivalent: openbsd-alpha is configured so that `long` is
> 64 bits, and hence `quad_t` is typedef'ed to `long`.
> In that particular case, the printf-like attribute doesn't work as
> intended.

> If `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(long)` on openbsd-alpha, it should work
> anyway - i.e. `%ld`, `%lld`, and `%qd` should be interchangeable. On OpenBSD/alpha, `sizeof(long) == sizeof(long long) == 8`.

Several platform-specific length options came to exist prior to widespread use of the ISO C99 extensions, `q` was one of them. It was used for integer types, which causes `printf` to expect a 64-bit (quad word) integer argument. It is commonly found in BSD platforms.

However, both of the C99 and C11 says nothing about length modifier `q`. The macOS (BSD) manual page for `fprintf()` marks `q` as deprecated. So, using `ll` is recommended in stead of `q`.

**References:**

https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/1999-02n/msg00166.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string

[https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7)

Comment: `printf` formats are implemented by the runtime library, not by the compiler. This is not a gcc (or egcs, or llvm) issue. On my Ubuntu 20.04 system, for example, `%qd` works with gcc and glibc, but fails with gcc and musl -- same compiler, different runtime libraries.

Answer (score 8):

`q` means **quad word** format specifier in printf function which is used to handle **64 bits** comfortably on all machines.

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string):

> Additionally, several platform-specific length options came to exist prior to widespread use of the ISO C99 extensions:
>
> …
>
> `q` - For integer types, causes printf to expect a 64-bit (quad word)
> integer argument. Commonly found in BSD platforms

Comment: By the way, for future reference. There is a "answer your own question" checkbox at the bottom of the [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) form. It allows you to post them together, and not rush to post them a minute apart.

Comment: C99 says nothing about length modifier `q`, and neither does C11 (see [§7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function ¶7](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p7)).  The macOS (BSD) manual page for `fprintf()` marks `q` as deprecated.  The Wikipedia page does not describe it as a C99 extension, but rather as a platform-specific option that existed prior to the C99 extensions being created.

Comment: It is important to emphasis that this is a GNU C extension, it has never been part of the C language. I added the gcc tag to the question.

Answer (score 5):

One of most interesting C language related question to answer. The symbolic literal `“%qd”` represent as quad word, which is specified as used to handle 64 bits effectively with the `printf` function in the C programming language. Also just remember that, from 1999 edition of the C standard states that `sizeof(long long) >= sizeof(long)`, and one can infer that the range of `long long` has a size of at least 64 bits.

Comment: Since the minimum size of `long` is 32-bits, the fact that `sizeof(long long) >= sizeof(long)` only allows you to infer that the size of `long long` must be at least 32 bits.  However, [C11 §5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types `<limits.h>`](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.4.2.1) says: _… Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign. … minimum value for an object of type long long int
`LLONG_MIN` `-9223372036854775807` // −(2⁶³ − 1)_ which does require `long long` to be a 64-bit type.