# What %qu format stands for in printf()

Tags: c

What `%qu` format stands for in `printf()`.
Know that `%u` is unsigned, `%qu` never came across. When googled found all other formats apart from %qu

Comment: `%qu` = unsigned 64-bit integer (unsigned long long)

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Length_field) says "`q` For integer types, causes printf to expect a 64-bit (quad word) integer argument. Commonly found in BSD platforms. "

Comment: It may be help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50830312/what-is-the-purpose-of-format-specifier-qd-in-printf

Comment: Then %llu stands the same i suppose the was some use %qu

Comment: No, unsigned long longs have a minimum width rather than a fixed width. ULLs may well be 512 bits wide or even more.

Comment: @SushilKumar: `%llu` = 64-bit (unsigned long long) although it allows 32-bit architectures to use it.

Answer (score 4):

It's not standard, it's used in some Unixes (mostly BSD) to represent an unsigned quadword (64 bits). Hence the `q` as a type modifier, like `l` for long.

Answer (score 2):

It's an old BSDism that should not be used, from before C had `long long` types. From the [FreeBSD man page for `printf`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?printf(3)), you can see that, at least on FreeBSD, it was corresponding to the nonstandard type `u_quad_t`, and that it's marked as deprecated. I'm not sure if `u_quad_t` was ever formally specified as being `unsigned long long`, but the portable replacement is using the `ll` modifier with type `unsigned long long`, or using the `PRIu64` macro with type `uint64_t`.